# Where is the source code for mmap function?

Tags: open-source, library

So I was searching for sys/mman.h and ideally sys/mman.c
in https://opensource.apple.com/source/Libc/Libc-1244.20.1/ and didn't find it. Any idea why? 
Where could I find the source?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because of two reasons - why Apple does/doesn't do something and finding off site resources are both off topic here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you mean mmap.c - you can find the source files here:

https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/5394bb038891708cd4ba748da79b90a33b19f82e/libsyscall/wrappers/unix03/mmap.c
https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/master/bsd/sys/mman.h

The kernel part of the implementation where the functionality actually lies can be found here:

https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/5394bb038891708cd4ba748da79b90a33b19f82e/bsd/kern/kern_mman.c

Comment: Thank you! Apologies for being a bit incessant, but where do I go next? https://github.com/apple/darwin-xnu/blob/5394bb038891708cd4ba748da79b90a33b19f82e/libsyscall/wrappers/unix03/mmap.c#L34 the __mmap function doesn't seem to have any definition in the file (only declaration) - only a passing occurence in syscalls.map, when I searched the whole xnu sources for __mmap. I'd like to dig into the real wrapperless impl (ideally down to kernel space, I seem to be stuck ;) )

Comment: I have added a link to the implementation of the mmap functionality in the kernel.